# Why am I getting a "void could not be converted to int" error with JOptionPane.showInputDialog?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I have this assignment for school where I have to use `JOptionPane` to calculate the area of different shapes, but when I use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`, it turns red and the error code says that `void` cannot be converted to `int`. Can someone help me figure out how to use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`?

```
public static void areaTriangle(int base, int height)
{
    System.out.println(0.5 * base * height);
}

public static void areaCircle(int radius, double area)
{
    area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
    System.out.println(area);
}

public static void areaRectangle(int length, int width)
{
    System.out.println(length * width);
}

public static void calcArea()
{
    System.out.println("What type of area do you want to calculate?");
    inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type 1 for triangle, 2 for circle, 3 for rectangle, and 0 for none, then press ENTER.");
    int type = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);

    if (type == 0)
    {
        return;

    }
    else if (type == 1)
    {
        inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the measurement of the base, then press ENTER.");
        int base = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
        inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the measurement of the height, then press ENTER.");
        int height = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
        int areaT = areaTriangle (base, height);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of the triangle is: " + areaT);

    }
    else if (type == 2)
    {
        inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the measurement of the radius, then press ENTER.");
        int radius = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
        double area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
        int areaC = areaCircle (radius, area);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of the cicle is: " + areaC);

    }
    else if (type == 3)
    {
        inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the measurement of the length, then press ENTER.");
        int length = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
        inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the measurement of the width, then press ENTER.");
        int width = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
        int areaR = areaRectangle(length, width);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of the rectangle is: " + areaR);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    calcArea();
}
```

Comment: Please specifiy exactly where your problem is. Looking at your code, you should get an error when you do "int areaT = areaTriangle (base, height);" since you defined the return type of that method as void, and try to assign it to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the `JOptionPane` and everything to do with your `area*` methods

First you declare all your methods as void...

```
public static void areaTriangle(int base, int height) {
    System.out.println(0.5 * base * height);
}

public static void areaCircle(int radius, double area) {
    area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
    System.out.println(area);
}

public static void areaRectangle(int length, int width) {
    System.out.println(length * width);
}
```

But then you try and assign a return result to a variable when you call them...

```
int areaT = areaTriangle(base, height);
//...
int areaC = areaCircle(radius, area);
//...
int areaR = areaRectangle(length, width);
```

Which simply makes no sense.

Based on what you seem to be trying to do, you need to change your `area*` methods to return a value of some kind...

```
public static double areaTriangle(int base, int height) {
    return 0.5 * base * height;
}

public static double areaCircle(int radius, double area) {
    return Math.PI * (radius * radius);
}

public static int areaRectangle(int length, int width) {
    return length * width;
}
```

Then you can assign the return values from the methods to some variables...

```
double areaT = areaTriangle(base, height);
//...
double areaC = areaCircle(radius, area);
//...
int areaR = areaRectangle(length, width);
```